# Spring Boot - How to handle expired access token (custom implementation returns 500 and not 401)

Tags: spring-boot, access-token, resttemplate

I have a spring boot application that uses rest template to access a rest service.
This service requires an access token to provide you with a response (200 OK).

***In case the token has expired instead of 401 the service returns 500 Internal Server Error.***

Because it's a system that I cannot persuade / ask them to return 401 I cannot use a classic HTTP Interceptor to get a new token based on the response status.

What's the best way to get a new token and retry the call that got 500 Internal Server Error?
Should I use ControllerAdvise ? I am new to spring and I am kinda confused with the "proper" mechanics.

Comment: Does it provide you any other details except HTTP status code 500?

Comment: @sonus21 He provides certain message "The token has expired on bla bla" or "Invalid Token bla bla".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, Please check the exception type also check the other parameter(system error code, description) in response when you get a 500. If the exception type is related to AuthenticationException/Access Denied, then you can try the retry mechanism.

Simple pseudo code will be like.

```
   if(Http.Status_Code== 500){
           if(Exception instance of AuthenticationException){
                   //call to get the access token
                   // call the service again
                } 
            }
```

Also, you check for the Spring retry mechanism,

Spring retry annotations

**@EnableRetry** – to enable spring retry in spring boot project

**@Retryable** – to indicate any method to be a candidate of retry

**@Recover** – to specify fallback method!

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-retry-module/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The pseudocode should be placed in a ControllerAdvise method ? Or it can be a try catch in the original rest controller ? Right now i have a try catch block in the controller that implements the logic (catch 500 and check the message and get a new token before retrying the call).

Comment: you can use in a try-catch block. But a good way to use the inbuilt library of spring Retry. Also you can consider using Hystrix if you wanted to use it.  You can check for DLQ implementation in kafka(messaging system), when any API calls fail, push message to DLQ and consume again to make a call to service.

Comment: thank you for your time and your comment.

Comment: if you find answer is useful, you can accept it , it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: will do after the post stays up for some time (if it is the accepted answer others may be discouraged to give their opinion sometimes).

Answer (score 1):

Spring Retry fits your Usecase very well.

I will assume you getting `AuthenticationException` exception.

Here is a sample Code at the controller level.

```
@Retryable(value = { AuthenticationException.class }, maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(500))
@GetMapping("/testRetry")
public String loadData(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
    //your code
    return "Success";
}

@Recover  
public String recover(AuthenticationException t, int d) {
    System.out.println("recover method called");
    return "Error";
}
```

You can also make use of `@Recover` block just in case all your retry attempts are exhausted.
`backoff` will wait for `500 ms` before retrying.

Refer more in detail [here](https://ashishontech.xyz/spring-retry-in-action/).